# What kind of words does this PDA accepts

Tags: pushdown-automata

I have a PDA A = ({q0, q1}, Σ = {a, b}, Γ = {a}, δ,
F = {q1}), with these transition functions δ:

((q0,a,ε),(q0,a));

((q0,b,ε),(q0,a));

((q0,a,ε),(q1,ε));

((q1,a,a),(q1,ε));

((q1,b,a),(q1,ε)).

The exercise asks me to explain the structure of the words accepted.
I have designed the PDA but i'm having problems understanding what kind of words the PDA accepts.
Any kind of help is really appreciated.

Comment: I think it accepts all words with length bigger than $1$. This is probably not what you wanted this PDA to do...

Comment: This PDA is given to me by the exercise, i have to design it and explain what kind of words it accepts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that your acceptance mode is by final state and empty stack.

The loops around $q_0$ add one stack symbol for each input letter that is read. After this, the third transition reads an $a$ without touching the stack. Finally, all transitions around $q_1$ remove one stack symbol for each input letter that is read.

To reach an empty stack in $q_1$, the number of loops around it has to be the same as around $q_0$. Exactly in the middle there is one $a$ that takes you from $q_0$ to $q_1$.  Thus the language would be
$$\{w_1\cdot a \cdot w_2: |w_1| = |w_2|\}.$$